# installing second instance of reporting service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

getting confused here. I'm trying to install a second instance of reporting service sql server 2008 r2. Now does it mean I need to install a second instance of sql server or can i use the existing sql server instance to create anothe reportserver database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 2005 I know that you would have to run setup again to install another instance. I am not sure if they changed it in later versions, although I believe it is still the same.

Comment: another instance of sql server? or just reporting service? can we actually have two report server database on a single sql server instance?

Comment: well you can do either or both. You would have to run the installation again to get it installed with a named instance.

Answer (score 1):

See ["Installing Multiple Instances of Reporting Services"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403426(SQL.90).aspx) and ["Multiple Reporting Services instances on one machine"](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/mglaser/archive/2006/12/18/multiple-reporting-services-instances-on-one-machine.aspx). If you want to share one database, consider a [scale-out deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159114(SQL.90).aspx).

Comment: I have even before posting this question.. but no details provided on msdn (no step by step instructions).

Comment: I found that 1st link very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to install sql engine instance. You start an installation from SQL Installation Center and check only Reporting from features.