# Can we intall two instance of reporting services in same server

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

In my production server i have one reporting services instance installed. Now i need to install another reporting services instance in the same server which will points to different database. And this second reporting services will be accessed by different web application.

I came up with this design to minimize the cost of setup a new  server for reporting services.
I need to know, Will this be possible and how to do it with out affecting my existing reporting services in the server.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use multiple Data Sources on the same instance?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605096/installing-second-instance-of-reporting-service

Comment: I think this question is more suited for the dba exchange site

Comment: I thought of using multiple data sources on the same instance. But if i go with that solution i need to pass credentials to the data source from my existing application. It will be a problem. Thats why i think of having two instance of reporting services.

Comment: Why not just store the credentials in the Data Sources?

Comment: In my scenario, I need to access different database from my second instance of reporting services. If i go with single datasource pointing to dirrefent databbases, i need to send server name, database name like parameters when im calling reporting services. It will cause changes in my existing application. Thats why i think of having different instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is a bit old but this may assist you in your installation

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403426%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As Ian Preston suggested use one report server, with two data sources, where each data source points to a different database and/or server.

At the root level of your reporting server, create a folder for each project/application.

Within each project folder you can deploy your reports and their data source.

The data source will contain the login details to point to the appropriate database and/or server, without the need to pass the details in.

You can even use permissions to restrict access on the project folders if required.

It would look something like this:

```
ROOT
- Project1
  - Proj1_DataSource    (Points to Server1/Database1)
  - Report1.rdl         (Points to Proj1_DataSource)
  - Report2.rdl         (Points to Proj1_DataSource)
- Project2
  - Proj2_DataSource    (Points to Server2/Database2)
  - Report1.rdl         (Points to Proj2_DataSource)
  - Report2.rdl         (Points to Proj2_DataSource)
  - Report3.rdl         (Points to Proj2_DataSource)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have up to 50 different SQL Server Reporting Services instances on each server.